# Django Post Save Signal goes on looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

The below code goes on looping , after processing the value for profile_pic

my use case: when the value for profile_pic is passed while saving the model , I need to perform some operations on it and then save it  , if the value is null nothing should happen

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def resize_image(sender,instance,created,*args,**kwargs):
    if instance.profile_pic:
        ###### doing some operations on profile_pic ######
        instance.profile_pic=image_process(image)
        instance.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def resize_image(sender,instance,created,*args,**kwargs):
    if instance.profile_pic:
        ###### doing some operations on profile_pic ######
        User.objects.filter(
            id=instance.id
        ).update(
            profile_pic=image_process(image)
        )  # <- call update not save and you won't be looping.
```

Or it's better to use pre_save signal instead of post_save.

Comment: it is working when i am passing the value for first time (value is A) , but it failing when i pass the value B for same object again, only the previous value A is present in the db instead of B

Answer (score 0):

`post_save` is called after the instance is saved. In this method you still call `instance.save()` triggering another save which causes a loop. Instead use the `pre_save` signal and don't call `instance.save()`:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save


@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def resize_image(sender, instance, *args,**kwargs):
    if instance.profile_pic:
        ###### doing some operations on profile_pic ######
        instance.profile_pic = image_process(image)
```

> **Note**: Rather than using a signal it might be better to simply process the image in the form class's [`clean_<field_name>` method
> (Cleaning a specific field attribute - Django
> docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)